# windows form combobox drawmode empty list

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have a comboxbox set to dropdownlist. I want the box to have a white background opposed to gray, so I set the DrawMode to OwnerDrawFixed.
 With that set the combobox is styled correctly but the list is now empty on dropdown.
The forecolor is set to black, what is causing this?

Comment: Well `DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed` means _you_ want to draw the items. Either subscribe to `DrawItem` event and draw yourself or find another way to set the correct colors. Setting the `DrawMode` seems wrong to me to adjust only the colors. But I can't tell because you don't show or tell what parts of the appearance you need to change to "match the color of the other boxes".

Comment: @RenéVogt is right. You can find examples of how to draw the items, for example [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1767/Implementing-an-OwnerDrawn-ComboBox)

Answer (score 0):

You need to draw this yourself then:

```
listBox.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
listBox.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(listBoxEvent);

private void listBoxEvent(object sender, 
System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    // Draw the background of the ListBox control for each item.
    e.DrawBackground();
}
```

This is at a minimum.